# Post form data to two urls using http get

Tags: php, curl, get, url-parsing

Please help, I have a simple web form and when the submit button is pressed I would like the form to post the data to two URLs, while redirecting to one of them immediately.

Here's what I have setup on the php redirect page after form submit. How can I add the 2nd URL and redirect to one of them successfully?

```
<? $aff = $_GET['aff'] ; $click_id = $_GET['click_id'] ; $email = $_GET['from']; $fname = $_GET['name_(awf_first)']; $lname = $_GET['name_(awf_last)']; $zipcode = $_GET['custom_zipcode']; $address = $_GET['custom_address']; $phone = $_GET['custom_phone_number']; $state = $_GET['custom_state']; $city = $_GET['custom_city']; $subid = $_GET['meta_adtracking'] ; $cblink = $_GET['cblink']; $keyword = $_GET['keyword'] ; $keyword = eregi_replace('[^a-z0-9 ]', '2', $keyword); ?> <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT=0;URL="http://ian.smileymedia.com/r2/?placementID=shopper&email=<?print $email?>&fname=<?print $fname?>&lname=<?print $lname?>&state=<?print $state?>&zip=<?print $zipcode?>&hphone=<?print $phone?>&mphone=<?print $phone?>&country=US&pubSubID=<?print $subid?>&city=<?print $city?>&addr=<?print $address?>">
<html>
<body>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Add handler on submit event.
2. Send data to the first url using AJAX.
3. Send data to main url using standard method like form.submit();

Try using like this:

```
<form onsubmit="submit();return false;">
.....
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function submit()
{
 var form = document.getElementById('formName');

 using ajax - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest
 return form.submit();
}
```

Comment: This is not problem. You can write this code in php file. I put down example of invoking custom handler during submit form and this one should be done using javascript.

Comment: @andrej: but then if thay have js disable he only gets one form. If hes already got php invlolved hes better off making a separate `curl` request tot he form hes NOT redirecting to, and then cin tinuing as normal... or assuming code to handle both requests is directly on his project then he could just process the values twice (once for each "action") and then redirect. Either way there is no reason to get JS involved.

Comment: @prodigitalson How do i process the values twice and then redirect?

Comment: You need to post what each server-side operation does to the values... otherwise i have no idea.